# Minimizing MySQL downtime during OS update?

Tags: mysql

Alright, this one should be simple. We would like to be able to perform scheduled OS updates on production DB nodes w/o excessive downtime. Our setup:

- MariaDB Primary "W1" (write+read)
- MariaDB Async Replica "R1" (read only)

In off-hours, "slow time", there are ~100 active connections coming from 10-15 app nodes (AWS cloud) generating about 5-10 TPS.

**The way we plan on doing this (through automation)**

1. Create a 2nd Replica (R2) based on R1 with the latest OS patches applied to it. Reconfigure the nodes to hit W1+R2 in place of W1+R1 [OK; no service interruption so far]
2. Discard R1, no use of it anymore.
3. *(Service interruption starts now)* Allow existing in-flight transactions to finish gracefully on W1 but block new transactions on it with `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`.
4. When the FLUSH... command finishes and we (somehow) determined that the async-replica is fully sync'ed, we change the roles of the servers and remap in DNS: W1 is R1 and R2 is W1
5. Bounce client nodes to pick up the DNS change and reconnect into the new setup.
6. If everything works, the R1 (old W1) is still outdated wrt OS patches, but that's easy update w/o service interruption, per point #1.

During the points 3-5 the system is briefly offline and clients see errors. The time should be short but appears unavoidable (w/o relying on Galera which we have other issue with [BUG MDEV-18641](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18641)).

If there is another - w/o service interruption - way to accomplish above, I'm very curious.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Where to you configure R2 to be the Master of W1?

Comment: In #4, when the FLUSH... command finishes we'd issue the CHANGE MASTER TO...

Comment: And turn on log_bin and turn off read_only and ...